# Remove Horizontal Scroll Bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to remove the horizontal scroll bar that is appearing on the website that I am working on at [Real Estate Website Scroll Bar Issue](http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/)

I think it might be in the bootstrap.min.css file:

```
{.table-responsive{width:100%;margin-bottom:15px;overflow-y:hidden;;-ms-overflow-style:-ms-autohiding-scrollbar;border:1px solid #ddd}.table-responsive>.table{margin-bottom:0}
```

But, that is a reference to a table. So I am not sure how to get rid of the scroll bar. Any help would be great. Thanks, Beth

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can either set:

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Or fix what is causing the grid system to overflow. I see you are overriding the default bootstrap grid styles. I suggest you leave bootstrap to handle the rows and columns widths and paddings.

Answer (score 1):

You have `.row` classes that are not a child of `.container` or `.container-fluid`. One is `.containerNew -> .row` and another is `#about -> .row`. Bootstrap requires `.row` be a direct child of `.container` or `.container-fluid` because `.row` has a negative left/right `margin` that works within left/right `padding` in `.container` and `.container-fluid`. So the negative `margin`s on `.row` are creating the horizontal scrollbar.

You also have 2 `#about` sections - an ID can only exist on the page once.